# Running malloc() in an infinite loop

Tags: c, malloc

Malloc function on success returns pointer to the memory location allocated and returns null value on failure. If I put malloc() in an infinite while loop, will this loop ever stop? After malloc() allocates the entire memory available, will it stop execution or just keep returning null value?

Comment: did you try what happens?

Comment: Did you try? (You should!)

Comment: @apoorvasomani How/why did you ask this question then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, it's like at the bank. Processes can together have borrowed more than there's available but it's OK unless they try to use it. Only then does the kernel back it up with real memory (or a piece of the swap partition). If all real memory and the swap partition are exhausted, the kernel should run the OOM (Out of Memory Killer) and get the culprit first.

If I just `malloc` without trying to use it, the kernel lets me on living, but I start getting NULLs from malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ while(1){ printf("%lu\n",(long unsigned)malloc(1024*1024*1024)); } }
```

Output:

```
140725756837904
140724683091984
140723609346064
140722535600144
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

This alone won't cause swapping of anything because I'm just getting (possibly unfulfillable) promises for memory, and it's not backed up by real memory until I hold the kernel to that promise by trying to do stuff with those returned pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Repeated calls to `malloc` this way will just keep returning null pointers forever. (However, if you try to use that null pointer, you'll of course get a segfault).

This is different behavior from `new` in C++, which throws `bad_alloc` if it can't allocate new memory.

Comment: Dereferrencing NULL pointers generally tends to do that regardless of how they're obtained.  :D